# Can I use the word "flesh" when referring to plants/crops?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, plant-physiology

If not, what would be a more appropriate word?

> Those potatoes had been potatoes eaten by worms. Now, they were nothing more than lumps of flesh with
>   nothing inside.

Comment: The *flesh* is what inside the *skin* (in [fruits](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flesh#flesh__6) but normally tubers) so "flesh with nothing inside" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: also, "they are" -> "they were"

Comment: @neeraj2608 Why? Doesn't the sentence say "Now"?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: It also says *had been* rather than *have been*, indicating the past.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre, like TimLymington says, the first sentence sets the context in the past.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your case, I think you mean what is called the "skin" of the potato, not the flesh. The skin is the thin outer layer of the potato, which is what would remain if worms had eaten the inside.

The word flesh *can* be used to mean some part of a plant which is *fleshy*. However, fleshy things are things which are somewhat like meat in texture, not things which are somewhat like skin. It refers principally to their texture not taste or location. An example would be the centre of some stems in plants which can contain material which is a tough mass, or the contents of some fruits.

Comment: Good. Explaining the different, conflicting, connotations of 'flesh' (outer and inner).

Comment: How would you describe the stuff inside the skin of the potato? Would you call it _flesh_? I think I might call the insides of a jackfruit _flesh_, but not those of a potato. Then what would the word be?

Comment: If someone were to say "flesh of the potato" I would understand it to be the main body, but think it was an odd usage. I would probably call it the "pulp" or "mass" of the potato or use some construction to mean the potato /per se/, eg "There was no actual potato left, only the skin". I think for something to be flesh it needs to have a certain integrity (non-crumbliness) or umami taste, which potatoes lack.

Comment: I agree. _Mass_ sounds more appropriate than _flesh_ for a potato.

Comment: Re "pulp" or "mass", also see Mari-Lou A's reply.

Comment: I would not use "pulp" for raw potatoes, as it implies a soft texture to me.

Comment: It seems that flesh *is* the accepted term for the inside of a potato, which surprises me (not for the skin, as the questioner seems to have been asking), as Mari-Lou A found. I suspect it's by extension from other, more fleshy fruits and tubers rather than any "fleshiness" of potato *per se*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can call the inside of potatoes *flesh*. It is the technical term used by potato farmers and also by nutrition experts.

> Only about 20% of the potato’s nutrition is found in the skin.  In
>   fact, most of the vitamin C and potassium are found in the potato’s
>   [flesh](http://www.potatogoodness.com/nutrition/), but that good for-you fiber is found in the skin.

> [Goldrush](http://wisconsinpotatoes.com/buy-wisconsin-potatoes/varieties/russet/)
>   Usage: Fresh market potato with low to medium gravity that
>   is great for baking, boiling, and processing. Tuber Appearance: Oblong
>   with russet skin and **golden flesh**.

Please note that the terms, *pulp* and *mass* are not mentioned once in the Wikipedia article entitled, [potato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato).

Comment: The example given by the questioner (with the worms) suggests that this is not how they are trying to use it, quite the opposite.

"Those potatoes had been potatoes eaten by worms. Now, they are nothing more than lumps of flesh with nothing inside." doesn't make any sense unless the user is taking flesh as synonymous with skin, unless they have some very odd potatoes. There is good reason to make that mistake: flesh and skin are almost synonymous elsewhere.

Comment: I take your point re pulp or mass, though. I'll edit my comment. I was really only replying to Tragicomic's question as to what I would call it and this isn't a forum, after all.

Comment: @DanSheppard I believe that the OP phrase is poorly formulated, but how can the "skin" of potatoes be described as lumps? If the potatoes had been completely consumed by worms, then I would describe the tubers as being shrivelled or shrunken in appearance e.g. *Now, they were nothing more than shrivelled/shrunken potatoes.* OR  *Now, they were nothing more than skin.*

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can:

Botany :
The edible pulpy part of a fruit or vegetable:
(halve the avocados and scrape out the flesh)
[flesh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flesh?q=flesh)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as an American with no special expertise in botany or agriculture, I would understand that the "flesh" of a potato was the starch inside the skin, but it's a weird construction.  Flesh of a fruit, like a peach, is a more common usage.  See Josh's answer, which includes "pulpy" as part of the definition.  Potatoes aren't pulpy.

The inside of a nut, that you can call "meat".

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the skin of the potato, it also makes good sense to refer to the "body" of the potato. Merriam-Webster defines "body" with the phrases:

"the main part of a plant or animal body ..." and
"the organized physical substance of an animal or plant either living or dead"

So the worms ate the bodies of the potatoes and left the skins.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to EL&U. This is a good start, but what's missing is the connection between *body* and *flesh*, since the question is about the latter word. Can you [edit] your answer to explicitly respond to "Can I use the word 'flesh' when referring to plants/crops?" (presumably *yes*), add the missing element (i.e. your main argument), and preferably add a hyperlink to the MW definition? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)