# What is the word for the edible part of a fruit with rind (e.g., lemon, orange, avocado, watermelon)?

Tags: single-word-requests

This morning I found one avocado I bought had become over-ripe: part of its edible part had changed color and was no longer green. So I was trying to describe this to my friend and I wanted to say "Hey I wanted to make some smoothie with this avocado but I found it over-ripe and part of its ____ has changed color."

I wanted to find a word to fill in the blank. I speak Chinese and in Chinese we call the edible part "fruit flesh". **I'm wondering what the English word is.**

A quick googling gave me the word "pulp", but it looks like "fruit pulp" is created by processing the "fruit flesh" and it's not the "flesh" itself.

Comment: Probably a duplicate, in spirit at least: [Can I use the word 'flesh' when referring to plants, crops?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167188/can-i-use-the-word-flesh-when-referring-to-plants-crops/167189#167189).

Comment: Why say “changed color” and not the idiomatic “turned brown”.  In fact saying “changed color” makes me think it was some other color besides brown although I have no idea what other color it could turn.  Maybe “black” if it had been way too long?

Comment: Note that the whole last clause here (‘part of it’s _____ has changed color’) could arguably be replaced with ‘rotten’ (if it’s actually rotted due to being over-ripe) ‘oxidized’ (if it’s just been exposed to air), or ‘discolored’ (a common generic term for what you are describing). Any of those three cases would sound much more natural to me (as a native AmE speaker from the north central US Midwest).

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, "turned brown" is more specific.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Thanks for the suggestion! Yeah, "rotten" looks pretty good in my case, too. I haven't learned "oxidized" or "discolored" yet but good to know them now!

Comment: @yaobin Note that ‘oxidized’ is rather specific in this case, and only applicable because the browning of the soft edible parts of an avocado that occur after long exposure to air are a result of the process of oxidation.

Comment: Just FYI the rind of fruits is usually edible too; some societies are just conditioned not to eat/like it.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has yet mentioned the word "pith." This word is definitely more literary than colloquial, and its technical definition (for plants) doesn't seem to include generic fruits. But I've heard it used in this sense (e.g., "the pith of an orange"). And it can also be used figuratively (e.g., "a pithy description"). Great word, at any rate.

Comment: @WillG I cannot speak for other fruits, but in the context of an orange (and all citrus fruits in general), the "pith" specifically refers to the white spongy layer between the edible fruit and the "zest" (outer peel), not the edible fruit itself.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I would guess that the most idiomatic way to complete that sentence is to leave the blank blank.  "I wanted to make some smoothie with this avocado but, it's overripe.  Part of it has turned brown." We don't care about the color of the avocado peel, so "turned brown" would only ever refer to the inside of the avocado.

Comment: I see what you mean and I suggest that avocado doesn't have a rind, but rather a skin… which matters more in this context than most.

That aside, consider Weather Vane's Answer…

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As the post suggests it can be called the

> **flesh**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1.2** The edible pulpy part of a fruit or vegetable.
> *halve the avocados and scrape out the flesh*

Calling it 'pulpy' doesn't mean it has been squashed. It means the soft part that isn't the skin/rind or pips/stone.

You don't have to call it 'fruit flesh', just 'flesh' will do when the fruit has already been mentioned.

> Hey I wanted to make some smoothie with this avocado but I found it over-ripe and part of its **flesh** has changed color.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/flesh).

Comment: On other flesh, other meats: *Belinda ate coconut meat off the shell. The meat of a plum. Cut one-third cup pecan nut meats in pieces. Arrange on a bed of romaine, pour over dressing, and garnish with strip of red pepper. They snacked on the pale yellow meat of the gru-gru berry.*

Comment: @tchrist That's very old usage though, and no-one alive today would use that. If the OP intended to read recipes from the 1700s then sure, but not for talking to someone else today

Comment: @Graham You're many centuries too early. People still refer to nut meats.

Comment: @Graham It’s rare in certain dialects, but usage is not purely anachronistic as you seem to imply. Part of the rarity is the fact that most people these days (at least in the US) use the name of the fruit or nut by itself to specifically refer to the edible parts, so there’s not much call for this type of usage to begin with.

Comment: @tchrist I have never (in UK) heard of nut meat (or even flesh), but *kernel* or its plural. But coconut meat, yes (a coconut isn't a true nut).

Comment: @WeatherVane Nutpicks are for digging out the meat from nuts per
[Lexico from Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nutpick): “***nutpick***: A thin, sharp-pointed table implement used to dig out the edible **meat from nuts.”**  
❶ [the mincemeat-pie–filling recipe from *Bon Appétit*](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/mincemeat-pie-filling) ❷ [The darkened areas have a bitter taste, while unaffected **meat** retains the normal pecan nut sweetness.](https://askinglot.com/how-do-you-describe-a-pecan)

Comment: @tchrist that's a good crop of search results, but I didn't mention the 1600s, and we don't see many hickory nuts here. Nobody I know says "nut meat", and "mince meat" here doesn't contain nuts but fruits.

Comment: My point is that this is all current, present-day English used every day, not ancient English that nobody uses anymore. Notice please that [per Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nutmeat), ***nutmeats*** are the kernel of a nut, which confirms Lexico's use. **All** nuts have nutmeats in today's English; it doesn't matter whether it's hickory nuts or any other kind of nut. Even piñon pinecones have nut meats. And mincemeat contains minced fruit; that's what they're calling the meat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129785/discussion-between-tchrist-and-weather-vane).

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree, but I would go slightly farther. At least to my ears, "fruit flesh" sounds a little odd. As you said, if the fruit has already been mentioned, then just "flesh" is fine. If its being referenced for the first time "flesh of the fruit (or specific type of fruit)" sounds much more natural to me.

Answer (score 13):

Deep question. More so than what it appeared to be on first look. I didn't realise English lacks a word for the edible part of a fruit that covers all cases, but it is more contextual than I expected. This means it assumes an understanding of what parts of fruit are edible whenever we are writing or speaking about it - which makes the conventions somewhat non-inclusive.

Scientifically, you are generally describing damage to what is considered to be the Mesocarp of a fruit.  Thats meaningless to most since it is not a general-use term, but I will use it going forward to refer to the specific structure.

More broadly you may be referring to the pericarp; though that is used to describe anything between and including the shell of the seed to the skin of the fruit, and is not useful in the case of an avocado where only the mesocarp is eaten.

Since the skin of some fruit can show a bruise, this may be useful in those cases. Even though it is at once more inclusive of structures that show a bruise and more ambiguous (since it includes one structure that will not bruise) than the use of mesocarp. In that case, though, we will refer to what we see on the skin as being the fruit, even when the skin is not edible; "the banana is bruised" or "the apple is bruised". So,if the exocarp is showing a bruise, it is usually safe to assume that the mesocarp is also bruised.

However in the case you used; avocadoes have the problem where the edible portion; the mesocarp, can have a bruise without showing evidence on the inedible skin; the exocarp, which is the cause of your frustration.

Since fruit covers a broad range of structures, even within the same family perhaps fruit flesh may be the best general-purpose phrasing, or just "flesh".

Though that is clearly a semantically overloaded word, the issue can be somewhat corrected by naming the fruit, eg "avocado flesh", though nobody would say "apple flesh" or "strawberry flesh".

This may be because the skin of those other fruits is frequently eaten, whereas only the giant tree sloth would eat the skin of an avocado, and they are sadly extinct and cannot contribute their experience to this question.

Perhaps the mesocarp of a fruit is only considered "flesh" in cases where the skin, or exocarp, is not commonly eaten; eg. "avocado flesh" "watermelon flesh" "orange flesh".

So I would suggest that you could say something like "The avocado flesh turned out to be bruised, but you did not know beforehand because the skin does not show a bruise."

I think this is weak due to convention, and I do not generally hear people describing the mesocarp of those fruits in that way. So it is not common phrasing (at least where I am) and will probably sound a little odd to many people, but they will know what you mean.

By convention, it seems to be more common that in fruits with an inedible rind or skin, the name of the fruit serves double-duty when referring to only the edible portion.

eg. "Hey I wanted to make some smoothie with this avocado (contextually, the entire fruit) but I found it over-ripe and part of the avocado (contextually, the flesh) has changed color." - though in the second usage, you would likely use the word "it".

For additional interest - the structures of a fruit, even within the same family of plants, can be expressions of different parts of the flower after pollination, so this cannot be assumed. - http://fruitandnuteducation.ucdavis.edu/generaltopics/AnatomyPollination/Fruit_Anatomy/

A reference I found only after I had written my reply above may be of interest to you:  http://www.ucavo.ucr.edu/General/FruitBerry.html

Comment: +1, but I disagree re *"Avocado flesh"*. This seems quite reasonable. Consider: *"Peel an avocado and separate the flesh from the stone"*. If you don't like *"flesh"* there, what word would you use instead? 139,000 hits on Google for *"avocado flesh"* tends to confirm this.

Comment: "I didn't realise English lacks a word for the edible part of a fruit that covers all cases" — why is "flesh" insufficient?

Comment: While it does seem less common to use flesh for apples, it's not unheard of https://www.simplyrecipes.com/fall_guide_to_the_best_baking_apples/ or http://terribleminds.com/ramble/2020/01/22/in-which-i-rank-grocery-store-apples-part-two/

Comment: Thank you, @Octothorn, for educating me on the subtleties of this topic.

Comment: @theonlygusti  - Fair comment, but I did suggest it may only be a regional thing that it sounds odd in general use to me in my location. 

I wouldn't refer to banana flesh or strawberry flesh, or as Pete mentions, apple flesh does sound strange.  I don't think I have ever heard the term used in that way.

Comment: @Octothorn I suspect the usage of "flesh" with regards to strawberry flesh is uncommon just because we eat the entire strawberry so there is little to distinguish it from. But "apple flesh" does not seem strange to me at all and flesh when referring to an avocado or some other fruits, especially fruits with pits to distinguish from the flesh, is relatively common.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman  I agree, and I think I did imply something like that.  While "apple flesh" sounds odd to me, I see no reason why it would not be a good descriptive, even though the skin is edible.

Answer (score 8):

*Pulp* is also fine to refer to soft meat/flesh in fruits.

**pulp** (n.)

> The soft, succulent part of a fruit usually composed of mesocarp
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pulp)

> The soft fleshy part of a fruit.
>
> *Jane suspends the pips in muslin to help the marmalade set, but I just use the juice and fleshy **pulp** from the inside of a lemon… it does the same trick.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pulp)

> **flesh** (n.)
> *Referring to fruit*: **pulp**, **meat**; *spec.* sarcocarp.  [F. Sturgest Allen; *Allen's Synonyns and Antonyms*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/ALLEN_S_SYNONYMES_AND_ANTONYMS/ZqweuM4ZH3AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fruit%20pulp%20meat%20flesh&pg=PA185&printsec=frontcover) (1921)

---

> An avocado fruit can be divided into three anatomical parts, namely, peel, **pulp**, and seed. [M. F. Ramadan; *Fruit
> Oils: Chemistry and Functionality*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fruit_Oils_Chemistry_and_Functionality/GAmXDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avocado%20pulp%22&pg=PA354&printsec=frontcover)

> In Java, pureed **avocado pulp** is mixed with sweetened coffee, while
> in Indonesia avocado-chocolate shakes are reported (Morton, 1987). [B.
> S. Schaffer et al.; *The Avocado: Botany, Production, and Uses*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Avocado/r0hpRJca3zEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avocado%20pulp%22&pg=PA23&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I think that "pulp" has a connotation that you've scooped it out of the fruit and, well, pulped it into goo

Comment: No doubt that comes from the **verb** *to pulp*: [to reduce to pulp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pulp). However, the noun can stand on its own as the fleshy part if you want it to. There are many examples of "scoop out the pulp" in books.

Comment: Pulp also has the connotation of the fibrous parts of the fruit interior such as in oranges, which is sometimes removed when making juice.

Comment: "Pulp" is the normal term, in British recipe books at least, for the flesh of a soft fruit. See, e.g., the first sentence of the recipe for passion-fruit jam in Yoram Ottolenghi's book 'Ottolenghi: The Cookbook': "Halve the passion fruit and use a spoon to scoop out the pulp straight into a small saucepan."

Answer (score 4):

I agree that both words, "flesh" and "pulp" do give a basic idea to convey that you are eating what is the actual tasty edible part of the fruit, or vegetable.  However I and my family have always used the term "meat" of the fruit for this application. For context, my family is American, English-speaking, and mainly from the Mid-West US and have been in the restaurant business, so food terms are standard in our household.  The term pulp describes the small pustule-like pieces that you find inside citrus fruits.  The pulp is a collection of many small individual fruit pieces (like tiny little grapes).  Apples, bananas, and avocados do not have these structures.  So the inside of those should be called meat, and not flesh.  The term flesh implies muscular tissue from an animal.  Though the term meat is also very commonly used as a term for muscular tissue from an animal (like a steak), the more biologically correct term to use for a piece of steak would be flesh. These fine nuances could be important if you are attempting to communicate clearly in polite mixed company.  Using the term flesh when talking about an avocado paints a somewhat carnivorous picture of eating animal flesh, whereas saying that the meat of the fruit had turned brown is more clear for this example.

Comment: Interesting to hear your use of flesh and meat, which are the reverse of how I would use them.

Comment: 'Meat' is the correct culinary term for the edible part of nuts.

Answer (score 2):

From the Webster online dictionary (dictionary.com) the second definition of "meat" is given as "the edible part of anything, as a fruit or nut". So I guess you can call it "meat". Plus, this is what I heard people say in America.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to use the term "edible part" (or "parts") when referring to fruit, and even to seafood, nuts, and other 'encased' or partly edible edibles. The phrase is somewhat generic, descriptive, unlikely to be misunderstood, but less anatomical than "flesh", "pulp" or "meat."

Answer (score 1):

I believe English has more words than any other language but there is still room for more perhaps` Merely tell your friend that the avocade was 'no longer edible' because it has gone bad. You could use the word 'inside' I suppose. Tell him the inside has gone rotten. or that it is inedible.